# Attach jdk source for 1.6.0_37-b06-434 and javadoc in Eclipse Juno on OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: osx-lion, javadoc, eclipse-juno, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have just installed the Java for OS X 2012-006 Developer Package from developer.apple.com and updated Eclipse Juno (the Springsoure toolsuite 3.1.0 version which is built on top of Juno) to use this JRE as the Execution environment and I also updated my projects to use this jdk.

In the JRE Definition dialog I attached source to classes.jar which is now pointing to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`

In this dialog I've tried letting the Javadoc point to Oracle online, to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home/docs.jar` OR `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home/Appledocs.jar`

Yet, it seems impossible to get to the source when I need to, both in debug view or when just clicking on the class. I get "Source not found" all the time.

In addition when selecting classes.jar in package view and then "open attached javadoc" from the "Navigate" menu, a browser window opens that seems to point to the proper localhost URL (via http://127.0.0.1:59109/help/nftopic/jar:file:/[local path to docs.jar] ) but the window is empty.

I've read several suggestions here on stackoverflow and on blogs, somewhat recent I think, and still I can't get this to work this time. You have any suggestions for a different approach?

**Update** One thing that actually does work is hovering over source code with some class or interface from the JDK which give me the **javadoc** in the little yellow popup window and if I doubleclick the class I get **the source** for that class. And now seeing source code in debug view seem to work fine too. Hmmm.

So my expectations on how to get to source and javadoc in Eclipse is erroneous?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javadoc not available in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823677/javadoc-not-available-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems everything was done right after all with pointing the javadoc to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/[jdk-version]/Contents/Home/docs.jar. and so on. It seems I have to read up on when I can see source and javadoc in Eclipse.

I'l leave this as is if someone else need to know how to do this currently.